# Scala equivalent of `data` declaration in Haskell

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming

I'm trying to write Scala code in a functional style, and want to create a custom type such as the following Haskell definition:

```
data Day = Mo | Tu | We | Th | Fr | Sa | Su
```

I know that Scala tends to borrow things from Haskell a fair bit, so was wondering if this kind of declaration is possible in Scala.

Comment: If **Scala 3** `enum` if **Scala 2** `sealed trait` +`case objects`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I think enumeration fits only for this simple example of a data declaration, and it's more like ADTs rather than enumerations.

Comment: Scala 3 enums should be able to express ADTs.

Comment: @Jasper-M Yes they totally are, what I meant was that although `sealed trait` + `case objects` does the trick for this scenario, but the question title is a bit more general, all ADTs cannot be expressed as `sealed traits` + `case objects` (in Scala 2), you'll also need some classes.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks. How do I then set a variable to take one of the  type's values? Like val foo: Day = Mo?

Comment: @hegash import everything inside object, and your code in the comment works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know Haskell that much, but I just had a quick look, and it seems like data declaration is kind of like an **ADT**(Algebraic DataType), given this example in haskell website:

```hs
 data Maybe a = Just a | Nothing
```

Similar concept to `Maybe` datatype of Haskell in Scala would be `Option`, which represents the possibility of existence of a value:

```scala
sealed trait Option[+A] { /* some methods */ }
final case class Some[+T](value: T) extends Option[T] { /* some methods */ }
case object None extends Option[Nothing] { /* some methods */ }
```

In Scala, these kind of DataTypes are almost always represented by a sealed trait, which is the product type, and some subtypes/objects, mostly known as sum types (`Some` and `None` in this case), much like in Haskell (`Just` and `Nothing`).

Now in your case, you don't need those constructors for your data, so you can both represent is as enums, or just use ADTs:

```scala
// using ADT

// define product type
sealed trait Day

// define sum types
case object Mo extends Day
case object Tu extends Day
case object We extends Day
case object Th extends Day
case object Fr extends Day
case object Sa extends Day
case object Su extends Day
```

Scala 2 enumeration (not recommended in general, but does the work):

```scala
object Day extends Enumeration {
  type Day = Value
  val Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr, Sa, Su = Value
}
```

Or Scala3 enums (your best choice if you're using Scala3):

```scala
enum Day:
  case Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr, Sa, Su
```

Comment: Wow, that sum type for Option is terrifying with lots of synatcitc constructs needed for something so simple. Is it fair to say that Scala sum types are constructed using language constructs that are overloaded in their purpose? I.e. that sealed traits are positively termed "multi-purpose, very flexible" or negatively termed "unfocused"?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: This is not specific to Scala. A "classical" OO language does not have algebraic sum types, but they can be emulated using inheritance: the sum type becomes a class and the data constructors become subclasses. This is how it works in any Smalltalk/Simula-like OO language, and this is how it works in Scala as well. However, as of Scala 3, there is native support for (G)ADTs, in the form of [*Enumerations*](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/enums/adts.html). The Scala 3 equivalent is `enum Option[+T] { case Some(value: T); case None }`

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Also remember that one of the design goals of Scala (at least originally, haven't looked at it in years) was bidirectional interoperation with Java. That means that anything that can be expressed in Scala needs straightforward rules for how it will be seen from the Java side. The most straightforward way in the JVM to represent something like sum-types is to use subclasses. So the original syntax of Scala wasn't even really *aiming* for direct encoding of sum-types so much as easy syntax for using subclasses to serve the purpose of sum-types.

Comment: `Data` *is* an algebraic data type, namely the 7-way sum of unit types. The syntax is virtually just syntactic sugar for `type Data = Either () ( Either () ( Either () ( Either () ( Either () ( Either () ()))))` and providing named data constructors for `Left ()`, `Right (Left ()`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

The Scala equivalent is an [*Enumeration*](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/enums/enums.html):

```scala
enum Day:
  case Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr, Sa, Su
```